# jar file not working with Java8

Tags: java, spring, jar, java-8, java-6

We have a jar file, which was compiled with java 1.6, and it was working fine.
Last month system were upgraded with java 8.

and now the java code gives the following error -

```
F:\globaltl\ConcurDump>java -jar ConcurDumpProcessLatest.jar prod
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/c
ontext/ApplicationContext
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.Applica
tionContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Is this issue because of the version upgrade?
The same jar used to work fine with older java version.

Comment: It is complaining about not finding a class (Spring stuff)

Comment: No, it's because you don't have the necessary jar file(s) on the classpath anymore. Something else has changed besides just the JRE. Is that a fat jar?

Comment: yes it is the fat jar... all jars were included in this file

Comment: Try to use `jar tvf ConcurDumpProcessLatest.jar` from command line and make sure that `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` really was included. Perhaps it was overlooked.